# How to make a regex that matches (replaces) a string and then leaves a section behind vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

Right I'm looking to make a regex which will turn the following input:

```
[[stateless society|stateless societies]]
```

Into this output:

```
stateless societies
```

While changing this input:

```
[[political philosophy]]
```

Into this output:

```
political philosophy
```

Basically I'm working with an xml file and trying to get lain text from it. I've actually managed to get a regex that picks the first of the two options (or just the first option):

```
\|([^\]]*)\]\]|\[\[|\]\]
```

But I can't seem to get this working to select the last most option between the double square brackets. I'd like to do this using replace as opposed to match, since I also need to remove a bunch of other stuff.

P.S. if anyone can come up with a more appropriate title, please edit it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (messy) regular expression I came up with:

```
\[\[([^\]\[\|]*\|)*(?<foo>[^\[\]\|]+)\]\]
```

With this regular expression, you would replace the input with the captured substring labelled "foo".

In C#, I wrote this snippet:

```
String pattern = @"\[\[([^\]\[\|]*\|)*(?<foo>[^\[\]\|]+)\]\]";
String input = @"[[stateless society|stateless societies]]";
String input2 = @"[[political philosophy]]";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);

System.Console.WriteLine(reg.Replace(input, reg.Match(input).Groups["foo"].Captures[0].Value));
System.Console.WriteLine(reg.Replace(input2, reg.Match(input2).Groups["foo"].Captures[0].Value));
```

and received this output:

```
stateless societies
political philosophy
```

Note, however, that if the input string doesn't have a match for the capturing group "foo", there will be an index-out-of-range exception on `Captures[0]`. You should check if there's a match first.

Similar code should be able to be written in VB.Net, as the Regex class is available for both C# and VB.Net.

**EDIT:** As requested in the comments, I have a modification to get the output from both inputs as part of one string. It doesn't do it all in one operation, but the code uses a simple loop. The substring "randomgarbage" is just to show that there can be text in between matches and it should still work fine.

```
String pattern = @"\[\[([^\]\[\|]*\|)*(?<foo>[^\[\]\|]+)\]\]";
String input = @"[[stateless society|stateless societies]]randomgarbage[[political philosophy]]";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
foreach(Match match in reg.Matches(input))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["foo"].Captures[0].Value);
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Adding some code to demonstrate how to get both the bracketed inputs and the text in between the bracketed nodes.

Note that there is a change to the regular expression; I added the "bar" capturing group to identify text that was between bracketed nodes. Since the brackets were used as syntax for the inputs, I've excluded them from the general text. Additionally, this should process the captures in the order that they appear in the text.

```
String pattern = @"(\[\[([^\]\[\|]*\|)*(?<foo>[^\[\]\|]+)\]\])*(?<bar>[^\[\]]*)";
String input = @"[[stateless society|stateless societies]]randomgarbage[[political philosophy]]";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
foreach(Match match in reg.Matches(input))
{
    foreach(Capture item in match.Groups["foo"].Captures)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
    }

    foreach(Capture item in match.Groups["bar"].Captures)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
    }
}
```

The generated output was:

```
stateless societies
randomgarbage
political philosophy
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. But I don't want to have to use reg.match because I have some other expressions I'm removing (using replace) and I was hoping to do all this in one operation!

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow; are you looking to be able to pull both the first and the last option into two separate outputs with one regular expression?

Comment: No. Basically in my comment I was saying I didn't want to use the match operation since I was planning on using one very long replace expression.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how could I modify your code to do the same with input and input2 as part of one string? Thanks

Comment: I added some code to my answer to demonstrate how that would work. While I could be wrong, I'm not sure you can take care of everything in one operation. On the other hand, the loop I added should find all of the matches in the string, which should take care of at least one of your requirements (once you modify it to fit your needs, anyway).

Comment: Thanks James. This is closer to what I'm looking for! One last modification I'm now working on is to not removed the text in the middle (randomgarbage) and similarly and text that appears before/after the brackets. If you have any thoughts let me know, otherwise you've been a great help this thus far anyway!

Comment: Glad to help! Is the text in between going to be in any specific format?

Comment: Assuming that the brackets will not be a part of the general text, I added some code to process the general text as well. It should process the various captures in the order that they appear in the text.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick `/(^(\[+))|[\|]|[\]+]/g`
http://jsfiddle.net/vmYDW/5/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response! This doesn't seem to work. It just removed the '|' from within the brackets.